# Post user scores from facebook game application

Tags: post, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post user scores (integer value) to facebook scores. My code is as follows:

```
<pre><?php getScores($accessToken) ?></pre>
<pre><?php postScores($accessToken, 'PLAYER_ID', 34) ?></pre>
<pre><?php getScores($accessToken) ?></pre>
```

and PHP code:

```
<?php
function getScores($accessToken) {
    $fbCurl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($fbCurl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/APPLICATION_ID/scores&access_token=' . $accessToken);
    curl_setopt($fbCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $scores = curl_exec($fbCurl);
    curl_close($fbCurl);
    echo '<h1>Scores</h1><pre>';
    var_dump(json_decode($scores));
    echo '</pre>';
}

function postScores($accessToken, $uid = 'PLAYER_ID', $score = 23) {
    $fbCurl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($fbCurl, CURLOPT_URL, sprintf('https://graph.facebook.com/%s/scores&access_token=' . $accessToken, $uid, $score));
    curl_setopt($fbCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    $data = array('score' => $score);
    curl_setopt($fbCurl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($fbCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_exec($fbCurl);
    curl_close($fbCurl);
}
```

After posting, value of score for this user is still 0. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you register you application as a game?  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/score/ for further setup and configuration information.